# Why Round(Fix(x))?

Tags: .net, vb.net, rounding

In the Reflector extract for `Microsoft.VisualBasic` it references [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Fix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ee1y7xa.aspx) in 3 places not including the `Fix(Object)` overload.

In each case it applies [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx) to the result. (Especially in `DateAdd` and `DateDiff`; the third use in `Choose` does subtract `1`, and redundantly cast to `Double` again before applying `Round`.)

When can `Math.Round(Conversion.Fix(x)) <> Conversion.Fix(x)` for `Double x`?

<s>(I'd check the Reference Source myself but I [can't find a download that *does* include `Microsoft.VisualBasic`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17350917/256431).)</s> *Reference Source now available [online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these references are then cast to `Integer` or `Long`:

`CInt` and `CLng` explicitly call `Math.Round` before their corresponding IL `conv.ovf.i4/8` cast when casting from `Single` and `Double`.

This enforces the [Banker's Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker's_rounding) that is a VB.NET known "quirk".

[`conv.ovf.i4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_ovf_i8.aspx) alone truncates towards zero, which happens to be the same as `Fix` (for the numbers that fit in an `Integer`, or a `Long` for `conv.ovf.i8`).

<sub>(When I originally typed in the question I thought I had checked that this was not the cause.)</sub>

For a while, Microsoft made the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) available, so I was able to confirm they were all enclosed in `CInt` or `CLng` and the `Math.Round` is added by the compiler.

The VB.NET "source" currently available at the above link now only provides the "reference assembly" which has no code :-(